# Concerns regarding my React custom hook for realtime Firestore listening, could this custom hook create multiple listeners?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I am curious if anyone could help me with my custom hook that listens for real-time data from Firestore.

For some context, the custom hook is meant for notifications which should trigger when a new document is added in the user's notifications_history collection on Firestore. I only want these to be notifications that they actually got after they rendered the page, so I order them by their createdAt timestamp & I also check so that they were created after a timestamp that I create on initial rendering. (I use the useRef hook for this)

The custom hook has an useEffect that requires the UID of the authenticated user, and I couldn't come up with any other solution than adding the uid to the dependency array of the useEffect, since the user is initially undefined. I can't help but feel like I'm doing something wrong though, and that there is a better solution.

One of my concerns is that since the useEffect has the user as a dependency, then perhaps this could create multiple listeners in case there are some hiccups with the authentication?

Another concern I have, which is more React related I suppose, is if there is any way I could make it so that I pass in the uid as a prop to the hook only when there actually is a uid? That would indeed solve the problems above so!

Here is the code:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

import { clientFirestore } from "@/frontend/client/firebase";

import {
  collection,
  query,
  limit,
  orderBy,
  where,
  onSnapshot,
} from "firebase/firestore";

import { useAuth } from "./useAuth";

const useNotification = () => {
  const timeRef = useRef(Date.now());

  const { user } = useAuth();
  const uid = user?.uid;

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    error: null,
    loading: true,
    notification: null,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!uid) return;

    const notificationQuery = query(
      collection(clientFirestore, `users/${uid}/notification_history`),
      orderBy("createdAt"),
      where("createdAt", ">=", timeRef.current),
      limit(1)
    );

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(
      notificationQuery,
      (snapshot) => {
        let newNotification;
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          const docData = doc.data();
          if (doc && docData) {
            newNotification = {
              id: doc.id,
              message: docData.message,
              createdAt: docData.createdAt,
            };
          }
        });
        setData({
          error: null,
          loading: false,
          notification: newNotification,
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        setData({
          error,
          loading: false,
          notification: null,
        });
        console.log(error);
      }
    );

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [uid]);

  return data;
};

export default useNotification;

.
.
.

in another file:

const data = useNotification();

 useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.notification) {
      toast.success(data.notification.message);
      playSound();
    }
 }, [data]);
```